# I get "=#N/A" when using formulas in PHPExcel

Tags: php, excel, phpexcel

The code below generates cells with "=#N/A". Any idea why? The same formulas work in a manually created excel file. Are the formulas too advanced or something for PHPExcel? Thanks!

```
$objWorksheet->setCellValue("A$excelRow", '=IFERROR(IF((INDIRECT("A"&ROW()-1))="Seq. #",1,IF(ISTEXT([@Column2]),COUNTA(INDIRECT("B20"):[@Column2]),"")),"")'); // Seq. #
$objWorksheet->setCellValue("J$excelRow", '=IFERROR(IF(OR([@Column6]="",[@Column9]=""),"",(INT(((([@Column7]-[@Column4])*3600)+(([@Column8]-[@Column5])*60)+([@Column9]-[@Column6]))/60))),"")'); // Duration min
$objWorksheet->setCellValue("K$excelRow", '=IFERROR(IF(OR([@Column6]="",[@Column9]=""),"",(MOD(MOD(((([@Column7]-[@Column4])*3600)+(([@Column8]-[@Column5])*60)+([@Column9]-[@Column6])),3600),60))),"")'); // Duration sec
```

Comment: Because I don’t want to spend days rewriting my whole app. Anyone else?

Comment: Seems like this is a reference error. Anyone know how `[@Column6]` etc works? I see that I can add defined names in Excel, but nothing like brackets and @ signs.

Comment: Ok, I upgraded to PhpSpreadsheet. No change. However I think there's a deeper problem with errors on reading my file. Starting a new thread.